# How to specify height on table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Please help! I haven't made a table in about a year and I was never well versed with tables anyways. Why does my table have a height of 269px and the first td with text is at the bottom, while the second td with an image with a height of 140px is at the top creating an unbalanced look? How can I make these cells flush?

```
<table style="width:600px;height:160px">
 <tr>
  <td style="width:380px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
   <p style="font-size:1.25em;text-align:center;">xxxxxxxxxx</p></td>
  <td style="width:180px;">
   <img src="xxxxxx.jpg" width="180" height="140"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

P.S. All margins, padding, borders set to 0 in css reset. plus for tables I have      border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/gJhv9/1/ like this?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to put your styling into your stylesheet; it looks very sloppy as is. This will make things far less cluttered and you'll be able to better control everything. I'd strongly recommend checking out codeacademy's Web Fundamentals track as it gives plenty of details on making and styling tables (just skip ahead to the stuff you need) in a far more eloquent manner than I could manage:

http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web

I hope that helps a bit; I'm sure you'll crush this problem quickly once you get back in the groove. Good luck!